# Windows SBS Console Crashing

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

I'm running a Small Business Server 2008 and whenever we attempt to add a new user, or multiple users the Console just crashes - I've tried restarting the server, but can't seem to find any cause.

Has any one else experienced this and have any advice on a fix?

Thanks!

Comment: chkdsk & virus scans would be the first courses of action along with peek at the Event Viewer too. Completed? If so, outcome???

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430086(WS.10).aspx

Comment: +1 - I havent seen that one before, I'll bookmark that page for later!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, I've noticed that when the console is trying to load data is can sometimes 'hang' have you attempted to leave it a short period of time?

Which point of creating the user/users does the console stop responding for you?

Do you have any relevant information in the application event logs which could point us in the right direction? Has any new software been installed on the server?